# How do I set the opacity of a WMS requested layer in Android Google Maps API

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geoserver, wms

Hi I've followed the instructions on this page: http://www.azavea.com/blogs/labs/2013/01/wms-on-android/ to overlay an image using WMS request to Google Maps from Geoserver. It's working already. The problem is I want the layer/image to be a little less visible (more transparent) so that the map can be seen more. Been searching for days but I can't seem to find solutions using Java Android. Please help. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to edit that particular image/layer declared in the XML file. As you have map beneath that layer which you want users to see inspite of an XML element (might be a button) which is at the top of the map its better to configure that XML element so that it is transparent.

This is a small code snippet that shows how to do that:

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/button/layer"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/ic_your_button/layer"
android:background="@android:color/transparent">
```

Hope this would Help!!

Comment: Hi AniV thank you very much for the reply. But as provided in the tutorial, I'm not placing anything over the map. The Google Maps itself handles the overlaying of the image/layer which is retrieved from the Geoserver. I don't know how to tell it to reduce the opacity. Thanks! :)